ExcelScript.FilterCriteria - how to write a string for criterion1:
I need help on how to set up the ExcelScript.FilterCriteria.  I can sort by blank cells (criteria 2), but I can't figure out the string for criteria 1 to look at a reference cell and return data that is less than or equal to the reference date.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
let range = selectedSheet.getRange("A13:C160");

let expireDate = new Date("J2");

const filterCriteria: ExcelScript.FilterCriteria = {
  filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.custom,
  criterion1: "<=&expireDate",
  criterion2: "=",
  operator: ExcelScript.FilterOperator.or
}
autoFilter.apply(range, 0, filterCriteria)
}


I have narrowed the problem down to the criterion1: and criterion 2: lines above.
For criterion2: the text should read "=" to return blank fields.  After this change, my script will successfully filter the list and return only entries with blank cells in the date column!!
I have searched and search to see how I write the code for "<="&expireDate and none are working.  "<==" + expireDate, but none of these work.  I can't find how to write this kind of string in office script.  Any ideas?
